Where did ktor go in IntelliJ K2?
It seems as though ktor plugin is not compatible or available when using IntelliJ 2024.1.2 with the Kotlin Plugin running K2 Kotlin Mode. With K2 reaching rc1 today, is there a replacement for ktor or another way to still use ktor? The plugin is disabled after upgrade in IntelliJ.
I've tried installing or updating/rolling-back the ktor and kotlin plugins but haven't found a good way to still use ktor.

Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-343673/Ktor-plugin-is-incompatible-with-K2-mode
